# Python 2.7 cannot open CSV I just created....troubleshooting from other posts did not work

Tags: arcpy, python, csv

I'm using python 2.7 on windows platform. (I don't have a choice to upgrade - cannot import any non standard modules...work constraints.) I have written a csv file from a feature class. I then am attempting to re-format text in a column. For some reason I am unable to open the csv.

I get the following errors:

```
D:\JJ_Development\Projects\Basemap\Transportation>new.py
D:\JJ_Development\Projects\Basemap\Transportation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\JJ_Development\Projects\Basemap\Transportation\new.py", line 199, in <module>
    newlabel()
  File "D:\JJ_Development\Projects\Basemap\Transportation\new.py", line 97, in newlabel
    with open(rc_existing, 'rb') as csvfile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\JJ_Development\\Projects\\Basemap\\Transportation\\roadcore'
```

- Both the csv and the python script are in my current working directory.
- The csv is not read only.
- I can open the csv in both notepad++ and arcmap with no issues.
- The file is not locked...I have restarted computer and have changed the name as well as copying over a fresh script.

I'm posting a snippet of csv creations (works) and then errors on the line "with open" (obviously this is not the full code)

```
    #********DATA AND PATHS********
curr_dir = os.getcwd()
print(curr_dir)
arcpy.env.workspace = (curr_dir)

#mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'D:\JJ_Development\Projects\Basemap\Transportation\Labels.mxd')
#in_fc = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, 'RoadCore_test2')[0]
fc = (r'D:\JJ_Development\Projects\Basemap\Transportation\Roads.gdb\RoadCore_Existing')

fields = ["ID", "ADMIN_ORG", "RTE_CN", "GIS_MILES"]
identical = ["ID", "ADMIN_ORG", "RTE_CN"]
labels = []

rd_names = (' ROAD', ' STREET', ' DRIVE', ' BLUFF', ' COVE',' LOOP', ' LANE', ' RD', ' LN', ' DR')


#********Initial FS Roadcore Existing Data Cleanup********
rc_existing = os.path.join(curr_dir, 'roadcore')

def test():
    fields = ["ID", "ADMIN_ORG", "RTE_CN", "GIS_MILES"]

    with open('{}.csv'.format(rc_existing), 'wb') as outf:
        dw = csv.DictWriter(outf, fieldnames=fields)
        dw.writeheader()
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as rows:
            for row in rows:
                if row[3] == 0:
                    pass
                elif row[3] == None:
                    pass
                else:
                    dw.writerow(dict(zip(fields, row)))
    print "File written: {}".format(rc_existing)
    outf.close()


#********FORMATTING LABELS********
def newlabel():
    with open(rc_existing, 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        for row in reader:
            print('csv open')

    # with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(rc_existing, fields) as sc:
        # for row in sc:
            # if (row[0].startswith(' ')):
                # labels.append('{}'.format(row[0].replace(' ', '')))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
    newlabel()
```

Comment: So, in the error message you posted first, you're opening the file in mode `rb`, which is read-only/binary. Then later in the code, at the line `with open('{}.csv`, you're opening it in mode `wb`, which is write-only/binary. There's a list of codes available to you [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/python-read-write-file). Are you sure you're opening it in the correct mode? What if you tried, simply, mode `r`? (If you're going to write in the file, try `r+`.)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do automated 'in line' edits with my open csv file. Evidently that is not possible. For this script to function I needed to create a temporary file for editing and use shutil.move to make write the temp file to permanent.

Lessons learned:

- You may get a blank space in between each line (I did) if you do not use binary mode. Thanks elrobis for response but that wasn't the issue.
- You may get a comma in between each output character if you use plural 'writerows' instead of 'writerow'.

Posting operable relevant code snippet here if anyone wants reference.

```
#********DATA AND PATHS********
curr_dir = os.getcwd()
print(curr_dir)
arcpy.env.workspace = (curr_dir)

fc = (r'D:\JJ_Development\Projects\Basemap\Transportation\Roads.gdb\RoadCore_Existing')

rc_existing = os.path.join(curr_dir, 'roadcore')
roadcore = r'D:\JJ_Development\Projects\Basemap\Transportation\roadcore.csv'


fields = ["ID", "ADMIN_ORG", "RTE_CN", "GIS_MILES"]
identical = ["ID", "ADMIN_ORG", "RTE_CN"]
labels = []

rd_names = (' ROAD', ' STREET', ' DRIVE', ' BLUFF', ' COVE',' LOOP', ' LANE', ' RD', ' LN', ' DR')

#********Initial FS Roadcore Existing Data Cleanup********

def test():
    fields = ["ID", "ADMIN_ORG", "RTE_CN", "GIS_MILES"]
    with open('{}.csv'.format(rc_existing), 'wb') as outf:
        dw = csv.DictWriter(outf, fieldnames=fields)
        dw.writeheader()
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as rows:
            for row in rows:
                if row[3] == 0:
                    pass
                elif row[3] == None:
                    pass
                else:
                    arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management(fc, identical)
                    dw.writerow(dict(zip(fields, row)))
    print "File written: {}".format(rc_existing)
    outf.close()

#********CREATE TEMP FILE FOR LABEL FORMATTING********
filename = roadcore
rc_temp = NamedTemporaryFile('w+b', delete=False)#default should be binary. Adding binary causes an os.unlink error. 

def temp_file():
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvFile, rc_temp:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        writer = csv.writer(rc_temp, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        for row in reader:
            if row[1] == None:
                pass
            elif row[0].startswith(' '):
                labels.append('{}'.format(
                                        row[0]
                                        .replace(' ', '')))
            elif row[1].startswith('01'):
                labels.append('{}'.format(
                                        row[0]
                                        .lstrip(ascii_letters)
                                        .replace(' ', '')
                                        .replace('.', '-')
                                        .lstrip('0')))
            elif row[1].startswith('02'):
                labels.append('{}'.format(
                                        row[0].lstrip(ascii_letters)
                                        .replace(' ', '')
                                        .replace('.', '-')
                                        .lstrip('0')))
            elif row[1].startswith('03'):
                labels.append('{}'.format(
                                        row[0]
                                        .lstrip(ascii_letters)
                                        .replace(' ', '')
                                        .replace('.', '-')
                                        .lstrip('0')))
            elif row[1].startswith('04'):
                labels.append('{}'.format(
                                        row[0]
                                        .lstrip(ascii_letters)
                                        .replace('-ADMIN', '')
                                        .replace('-A-ADMIN','')
                                        .replace('-PARKING','')[2:]
                                        .lstrip('0')
                                        .replace('.', '-')))
            elif row[1].startswith('05'):
                labels.append('{}'.format(
                                        row[0].rstrip('0')
                                        .lstrip('0')
                                        .lstrip(ascii_letters)
                                        .replace('.', '-')))
            elif row [1].startswith('0501'):
#Note: 0501 forest label data entered in unicode.
                labels.append('{}'.format(
                                        row[0].rstrip('0').split('.',1)
                                        .replace(' ', '')))
            elif row[1].startswith('06'):
                labels.append('{}'.format(
                                        row[0].rstrip('0')
                                        .replace('.', '-')
                                        .lstrip(ascii_letters)))
            elif (row[1].startswith('06')) and (row[0].endswith(rd_names)):#if id field contains rd names ASCII strip all alpha
                labels.append('{}'.format(
                                        row[0].rstrip(ascii_letters)))
            elif row[1].startswith('0816'):
                pass
            elif row[1].startswith('08'):
                labels.append('{}'.format(
                                        row[0].lstrip(ascii_letters)))
#Note: R08 label data entered in unicode.
            elif row[1].startswith('09'):
#Note: R09 label data entered in unicode.
                labels.append('{}'.format(
                                        row[0].lstrip('0')
                                        .replace('.', '-')
                                        .lstrip(ascii_letters)))
            elif row[1].startswith('10'):
                labels.append('{}'.format(
                                        row[0]
                                        .lstrip('0')
                                        .replace('.', '-')
                                        .lstrip(ascii_letters)))
            else:
                labels.append(row[0])
            writer.writerow(row)
    #print(labels)
    shutil.move(rc_temp.name, filename)
    print('Label formatting done')
```